# Why doesn't Silverlight support BMP/JPEG/PNGBitmapEncoder?

Tags: silverlight, writeablebitmap

I am trying to save a `WriteableBitmap` to local in Silverlight using `SaveFileDialog`. A question similar to mine is asked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394109/how-to-save-bitmapimage-writeablebitmap-using-savefiledialog-in-silverlight-3).

And the answers show several opensource encoders and workarounds. 
They work fine.

But why silverlight doesn't support encoders for JPEG/PNG/BMP itself while .NET framework and WPF support [all of them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970689.aspx)? Why should we apply for third party classes?

I thought for a whole night, but failed to figure out why. Since I am not allowed to use third party classes, I have to write an encoder myself.:(

Comment: **Why** aren't you allowed to use 3rd-party libraries? That's a horrible restriction.  That's like being told to build a computer without using 3rd-party hardware (eg, CPUs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you aren't allowed to *purchase* third-party components, then use open source.  Take a look at FJCore:

http://code.google.com/p/fjcore/

If you aren't allowed to use *any* classes you didn't write, you need to have a serious conversation with management.

Comment: Well, I'm just confused why silverlight doesn't support encoder while other products like wpf have this ability. And I wrote a class in my own to encode byte[] to .bmp....

Comment: I think it probably has to do with copyright on JPEG encoders.