# Save a grid as bytes

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-toolkit, silverlight-5.0

I want to develop a silverlight project like ms paint. i found a example. but it has a problem. i can't save DrawingArea grid as a image file or bytes. i don't how save DrawingArea grid into bytes. plz help me

```
            <UserControl
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" x:Class="SilverlightPaintApplication.MainPage" 
            Width="805" Height="600" mc:Ignorable="d" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
            <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FFFFFFFF" Width="Auto" >

                ...

            <Grid x:Name="DrawingArea" Margin="0,0,-5,8" MouseMove="DrawingArea_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonDown="DrawingArea_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="DrawingArea_MouseLeftButtonUp" Background="#FFFFFFFF"/>

                ...

            </Grid>
        </UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the solution is to use a [Writeable Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and save that out [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1394466/10893).